# MSSql ISNULL query

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select ISNULL(c.name,'any') from (select Name from Orders where ID = '123')

select ISNULL((select Name from Orders where ID = '123'),'any')
```

Orders table have two columns

```
1. ID
2. Name
```

and data in Orders is

```
ID    Name
121   abc
124   def
```

First Query is not returning any result whereas second query is giving any as result. What is the difference

Answer (score 1):

The first form uses a subquery as a table source, in its `FROM` clause; it can return between zero and many rows.

For each of the rows that the subquery returns, the `ISNULL` expression is evaluated. But if the subquery returned no rows, then the final output contains no rows.

The second form uses a `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause - which will always produce a result set containing exactly one row. It then also uses a *scalar* subquery (by introducing a subquery in a location where a scalar value is expected) - that has to either produce zero or one results. If the subquery produces zero results, then `NULL` is substituted.

---

So, the differences between the two are that the first query can return between zero and many rows, and the `ISNULL` expression is evaluated for each row. Whereas the second query always produces exactly one row, and if the subquery returned multiple results, an error is produced.